# svn2git migration - tags not being copied

Tags: git, github, svn, version-control, svn2git

I've used [svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git) (running on Debian) to try migrating an SVN repository to Git and then pushed to GitHub:

```
svn2git https://localhost/svn/test-repository/space-invaders --username user
git remote add origin https://github.com/my-username/space-invaders.git
git push --all
```

The source SVN repository has lots of tags:

[image]

But afterwards, no tags have made it into GitHub:

[image]

I've seen the [FAQ](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git#faq), but to be honest I don't really understand it. The tags aren't showing up in the `gitk` UI either.

I did try using [GitHub's own importer](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-source-code-to-github/about-github-importer), but this didn't preserve any of the history which was very frustrating.

`svn2git` output:

```
hint: Using 'master' as the name for the initial branch. This default branch name
hint: is subject to change. To configure the initial branch name to use in all
hint: of your new repositories, which will suppress this warning, call:
hint:
hint:   git config --global init.defaultBranch <name>
hint:
hint: Names commonly chosen instead of 'master' are 'main', 'trunk' and
hint: 'development'. The just-created branch can be renamed via this command:
hint:
hint:   git branch -m <name>
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/user/space-invaders/.git/
Authentication realm: <https://localhost:443> VisualSVN Server
Password for 'user':
Using higher level of URL: https://localhost/svn/test-repository/space-invaders => https://localhost/svn/test-repositoryAuthentication realm: <https://localhost:443> VisualSVN Server
Password for 'user':
r1 = bcfeab442a701895d74113928cbb08bacefc9602 (refs/remotes/svn/trunk)
        A       thecode
r3 = 2c0b0ea6b3517e461349ac8249ee89fa1df96367 (refs/remotes/svn/trunk)
Found possible branch point: https://localhost/svn/test-repository/space-invaders/trunk => https://localhost/svn/test-repository/space-invaders/tags/1.0.47, 3
Found branch parent: (refs/remotes/svn/tags/1.0.47) 2c0b0ea6b3517e461349ac8249ee89fa1df96367
Following parent with do_switch
Successfully followed parent
r4 = 48ce984471a4343d07c8b079d63641a1da81389b (refs/remotes/svn/tags/1.0.47)
        M       thecode
r5 = 289433f53f435964559244876638de2fa973e4a3 (refs/remotes/svn/trunk)
Found possible branch point: https://localhost/svn/test-repository/space-invaders/trunk => https://localhost/svn/test-repository/space-invaders/branches/branch_2.0.20_bleh, 5
Found branch parent: (refs/remotes/svn/branch_2.0.20_bleh) 289433f53f435964559244876638de2fa973e4a3
Following parent with do_switch
Successfully followed parent
r6 = 9dff5da18bdd734e50ec187a314d1c61fad8b41c (refs/remotes/svn/branch_2.0.20_bleh)
        M       thecode
r7 = bc1495b49c729cf789d896847ba7b4b6b55e01f1 (refs/remotes/svn/branch_2.0.20_bleh)
        M       thecode
r8 = d73dc60e8518c1695e2a6d3f0e10d11bfdbfd1bd (refs/remotes/svn/trunk)
Found possible branch point: https://localhost/svn/test-repository/space-invaders/trunk => https://localhost/svn/test-repository/space-invaders/tags/2.0.24, 8
Found branch parent: (refs/remotes/svn/tags/2.0.24) d73dc60e8518c1695e2a6d3f0e10d11bfdbfd1bd
Following parent with do_switch
Successfully followed parent
r9 = 491aa2e3f1a64f032ebdd5e76577302ebdfdbabf (refs/remotes/svn/tags/2.0.24)
Checked out HEAD:
  https://localhost/svn/test-repository/space-invaders/trunk r8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`svn2git` was working correctly - I could see it when I ran `git tag` on the local repository `svn2git` produced.

But git `push --all` only pushes branches, not tags - I needed to run `git push --tags` as well.

Following this the tags were showing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your repo has non-standard layout (visible even of dirty screenshot) for tags, but you used command-line of standard SVN-layout
2. Build a real "plan" of tree for your repo
3. Read svn2git Readme carefully
4. Define **all needed for your case** options and option's values
5. Repeat export, check for (possible) errors
6. Repeat p.5 as much, as needed
7. Have fun

Comment: thanks for your response. Could you define what’s non-standard?

Comment: I've updated my question with the directory structure of the SVN server.

Comment: @Jakg - redone it (tree) with plain `svn ls URL/OF/spaceinvaders` (paste **as text**). I still can't understand your tree, and https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIqsz.png show additional nesting of tags (AFAICS)

Comment: apologies, I'd tried to anonymise the screenshots and hadn't done it consistently. I've created a new repository for testing and put up more information in a consistent form. Let me know if something is missing.